# ORA-00904: "OVERDUE_DAYS": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I keep getting this error no matter what I change in my code. My code for my SQL is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE movie_rent_records(
rent_record_id NUMBER(8),
customer_id NUMBER(5),
copy_id NUMBER(5),
rented_date DATE,
returned_date DATE,
rent_fee NUMBER(5,2),
overdue_fee NUMBER(5,2),
overdue_days NUMBER(2),
CONSTRAINT movie_rent_records_pk PRIMARY KEY(rent_record_id),
CONSTRAINT movie_rent_records_fk1 FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id),
CONSTRAINT movie_rent_records_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(copy_id) REFERENCES movie_copies(copy_id));
```

The code for the insert statement is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO movie_copies(rent_record_id, customer_id, copy_id, rented_date, returned_date, rent_fee, overdue_fee, overdue_days) VALUES('00000001', '001', '00001', '5-SEP-2014', '6-SEP-2014', '2.99', '0.00', '00');

INSERT INTO movie_copies(rent_record_id, customer_id, copy_id, rented_date, returned_date, rent_fee, overdue_fee, overdue_days) VALUES('00000002', '002', '00002', '7-SEP-2014', '17-SEP-2014', '2.99', '7.92', '08');

INSERT INTO movie_copies(rent_record_id, customer_id, copy_id, rented_date, returned_date, rent_fee, overdue_fee, overdue_days) VALUES('00000003', '003', '00003', '10-SEP-2014', '11-SEP-2014', '2.99', '0.00', '00');

INSERT INTO movie_copies(rent_record_id, customer_id, copy_id, rented_date, returned_date, rent_fee, overdue_fee, overdue_days) VALUES('00000004', '004', '00004', '23-SEP-2014', '28-SEP-2014', '2.99', '2.97', '03');

INSERT INTO movie_copies(rent_record_id, customer_id, copy_id, rented_date, returned_date, rent_fee, overdue_fee, overdue_days) VALUES('00000005', '005', '00005', '21-SEP-2014', '22-SEP-2014', '2.99', '0.00', '00');

COMMIT;
```

The error I keep getting is ORA-00904: "OVERDUE_DAYS": invalid identifier. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're inserting into the wrong table. You've shown the DDL for `movie_rent_records`, and that does seem to be what you're trying to populate, but your insert statements are for `movie_copies`. So to state the obvious:

```
INSERT INTO movie_rent_records(rent_record_id, customer_id, copy_id, rented_date,
    returned_date, rent_fee, overdue_fee, overdue_days)
VALUES('00000001', '001', '00001', '5-SEP-2014', '6-SEP-2014', '2.99', '0.00', '00');
```

What might be confusing you is that it's complaining about `overdue_fees` rather than earlier columns that maybe also don't exist in your `movie_copies` table, like `rent_record_id`, and probably everything except `copy_id`. I can see that could make you focus on that last column and miss the obvious mistake. That's because the parser tends to work backwards through statements - just one of its little quirks. (I'm sure there is, or once was, a good reason to do with the order the parts of the statement need to be checked to avoid ambiguity, but it's still a bit confusing sometimes).

In addition... your insert is supplying everything as string, so a lot of implicit conversion will be happening; and for the date columns that may not always work. Pass the correct types, explicitly converting if necessary:

```
INSERT INTO movie_rent_records(rent_record_id, customer_id, copy_id, rented_date,
    returned_date, rent_fee, overdue_fee, overdue_days)
VALUES(1, 1, 1, to_date('5-SEP-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
    to_date('6-SEP-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 2.99, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you I guess I been working on this to long the little things are slipping by me